# How can I split a dataframe into multiple columns when my column header has \ in the name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called ratings. It is a single column, named "tconst\taverageRating\tnumVotes", although it needs to be split into 3, separated by "\".

I understand that this statement can be used: `ratings[['tconst','taverageRating','tnumVotes']] = ratings.???.str.split("\",expand=True,)`

However, when I replace ??? with the actual column name, I get an error. I believe this is because of the \s in the column header.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the error?

Comment: `read_csv(... , sep='\t')`

Comment: BTW: `ratings["tconst\taverageRating\tnumVotes"].str.split("\t", expand=True)` ? And it has to be `\t` instead of \

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are reading the data in correctly? 
Looking at the header names, it looks likely that your data is actually `\t` i.e.`tab` separated (so, `\t` and `numVotes` make sense separately). In that case you should read your data like this:

```
pd.read_csv('http://language.media.mit.edu/data/public/unesco_langlang_20120722_iso639-3.txt', sep='\t')
```